# Does these two expression means the same, both functionally and memory wise? Or there is any difference like top level const and low level const?

Tags: pointers, c++11, constants, constexpr

The first code:
    const int i = 10; 
    constexpr const int* p = &i;

The second code:
    const int i = 10;
    const int* const p = &i;

Comment: Do you know what `constexpr` is?

Comment: Yeah its constant expression and const,contexpr has runtime and compile time differences. But I was asking is there any difference in usage?